# WSO IOTS: device token (OAuth)

Tags: wso2, iot

I have some question:

1. How to refresh `device token` with only `refresh token` in `device agent`?
2. How to find `device token` when token changed by device (use `refresh token`)?
3. And can I use one token for many device?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using IOT Server alpha pack.

(1) How to refresh device token with only refresh token in device agent?

For the virtual Fire alarm application in the Alpha pack we used only the access token. To use the refresh token in Alpha pack you have to use below standard process as it is not implemented yet.

1. Go to api-store using https://:9443/api-store/
2. Go to 'My Subscriptions' and get the consumerkey and secret key of virtual firealaram application
3. Get the refresh token from the properties file (deviceConfig.properties)
4. Call the token endpoint using the curl to refresh it

ex: curl -k -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=&scope=device_type_virtual_firealarm device_vf3ouabim2xu" -H "Authorization: Basic " -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:9763/oauth2/token

5. Update the config properties file with the new token

This will be fixed in the next release version. Pull request can be found in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins/pull/297

(2) How to find device token when token changed by device (use refresh token)?

When the device token changed by the refresh token, latest device token will get updated in the deviceConfig.properties file.

(3) And can I use one token for many device?

Yes, You can use one token for multiple devices in the Alpha pack. However this is not the correct approach, therefore we will be restricting to use only one token per device from the Beta release onwards

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if I have many devices, I must add device manual from `device manage`, right?

Comment: To add device manual (details) you have to write necessary extensions in IOT jaggery application pages as mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Writing+UI+Extensions

Comment: If I have 100 device, I must do the same things, can I do that without add device manual?

Comment: In IOT server we manage device connectors.  If you have 100 different device **types** then you have to manage 100 different device connectors. (Each of this device connector should consists of the relevant API,  UI extensions, agents, etc.). So if you have 100 device types, You have to write 100 different manuals through UI extensions. But if you have 100 devices for a **particular device type**, then you can register those devices using the device agent for that device type. (And only one device manual can be maintained to provide details of the device type)

Comment: You can refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Writing+Your+Own+Device+Connector to get an understanding of how to write device connector and necessary background details